# Persist Dynamically Added Controls w/ DataTriggers WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, persistence, caliburn.micro

I am currently working on a WPF project that uses Caliburn.Micro and have hit a snag I was hoping you could help with. I have a form that allows the user to add new fields to a separate form with the intention that these new fields will persist. I am able to create these controls dynamically with the following code:

```
        Grid tmpOuterGrid = new Grid();
        RowDefinition rowDefinition1 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition rowDefinition2 = new RowDefinition();
        rowDefinition1.Height = new GridLength(45, GridUnitType.Star);
        rowDefinition2.Height = new GridLength(55, GridUnitType.Star);
        tmpOuterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition1);
        tmpOuterGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition2);
        tmpOuterGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,10);

        Grid tmpInnerGrid = new Grid();
        Grid.SetRow(tmpInnerGrid, 0);
        tmpInnerGrid.Margin = new Thickness(10,0,0,5);
        tmpInnerGrid.Opacity = 0;

        DataTrigger d = new DataTrigger();
        Binding b = new Binding("DisplayFieldName");
        b.Source = _fieldNames[primaryNameBase + "FieldTextBox"];
        d.Binding = b;
        d.Value = true;

        Storyboard sbEnter = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation opAnimShow = new DoubleAnimation(1,new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1)));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(sbEnter, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
        sbEnter.Children.Add(opAnimShow);

        Storyboard sbExit = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation opAnimHide = new DoubleAnimation(0, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1)));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(sbExit, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
        sbExit.Children.Add(opAnimHide);

        BeginStoryboard bsEnter = new BeginStoryboard { Storyboard = sbEnter, Name = "beginStoryboardEnter" };
        BeginStoryboard bsExit = new BeginStoryboard { Storyboard = sbExit, Name = "beginStoryboardExit" };

        d.EnterActions.Add(bsEnter);
        d.ExitActions.Add(bsExit);

        Style st = new Style(typeof(Grid));
        st.Triggers.Add(d);
        tmpInnerGrid.Style = st;

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Name = primaryNameBase + "FieldHeaderText";
        tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(136,255,255,255));
        tb.FontSize = 14;
        tb.Style = (Style) App.Current.Resources["NexaLightTextBlock"];
        tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        tb.Text = fieldTextBox.DisplayText;

        Border underline = new Border();
        underline.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1);
        underline.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(136,49,250,250));
        underline.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        underline.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        Binding binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = tb,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
        };
        underline.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, binding);

        tmpInnerGrid.Children.Add(tb);
        tmpInnerGrid.Children.Add(underline);

        LowBorderTextBox lbtb = new LowBorderTextBox();
        lbtb.Name = primaryNameBase + "FieldTextBox";
        Grid.SetRow(lbtb, 1);
        lbtb.Width = 140;
        lbtb.Margin = new Thickness(10,0,0,0);
        lbtb.FontColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        lbtb.DisplayFontSize = 22;
        lbtb.Style = (Style) App.Current.Resources["NexaLightCustomTextBox"];
        lbtb.DisplayText = fieldTextBox.DisplayText;
        lbtb.LostFocus += FieldLostFocus;

        tmpOuterGrid.Children.Add(tmpInnerGrid);
        tmpOuterGrid.Children.Add(lbtb);

        wrapPanel.Children.Add(tmpOuterGrid);
```

I would then like these new controls to be persisted through application shutdowns. The approach I was thinking of taking was serializing the object into xaml and storing that in a file, and then reading this file and deserializing it to obtain the control object again, which would be added to my surrounding WrapPanel. This is all fine and dandy except for one detail. The controls that are created have a style with a datatrigger that is bound to a property of a NoteField object, there being one NoteField object for each of these types of control. I was planning on serializing the NoteField objects as well, so that I could just pull them back and hope that the binding would still be intact, but they implement the PropertyChangedBase interface of the Caliburn.Micro framework, and the NotifyOfPropertyChange() method is not marked as serializable. Here is the NoteField class:

```
[Serializable]
class NoteField : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _controlName;

    private bool _displayFieldName;

    public bool DisplayFieldName
    {
        get { return _displayFieldName; }
        set
        {
            _displayFieldName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DisplayFieldName);
        }
    }

    private string _fieldName;

    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return _fieldName; }
        set
        {
            _fieldName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FieldName);
        }
    }

    public NoteField(string controlName, string displayText)
    {
        DisplayFieldName = false;
        _controlName = controlName;
        FieldName = displayText;
    }

    public string GetControlName()
    {
        return _controlName;
    }

    public void SetControlName(string name)
    {
        _controlName = name;
    }
}
```

I am not attached to using this class, but it was the only way I could think of having dynamically generated properties to bind to from the xaml. So, I guess my question is: is there a way that I can dynamically create controls that have bindings in them that can persist through application shutdowns? Am I on the right track, or should I do something else all together? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You could try to wrap all your controls in a `DevExpress LayoutPanel` and then use the DevExpress's mecanisms to save the layout. This way, even styles and triggers will be saved.

Comment: I've never used any of DevExpress' stuff, but I would think that I would still encounter the same issue. Right now I am able to save the xaml for each dynamically created control (with the triggers and style and whatnot), but the issue lies in the property that the DataTrigger is bound to. It is bound to a property of an instance of the NoteField class, and once the application is shutdown, these objects get destroyed. So when the application starts again, the binding no longer works because those objects ceased to exist once the shutdown happened.

Comment: Unless DevExpress' stuff has a way of saving the objects that the bindings are bound to, do you know if they implement that functionality?

Comment: I don't remember why I talked about DevExpress, I thought you were already using it. Yes DevExpress has a mecanism to Save the layout but their components aren't free